# filtering two knockout arrays to find the difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockout and have two arrays.

I want to find the difference between the arrays, i.e. any items that are in the longer array that are not in the smaller one.

i have

```
    console.warn(items1); // 10
    console.warn(items2); // 11

    var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(items1, function (e) {
        return !items2.indexOf(e) > -1;
    });

    console.warn(filtered); // 10
```

How do I changes this to leave filtered with the 1 new item?

I've tried  `return items2.indexOf(e) > -1;`

I've tried switching the arrays around on the filter and return.

I've tried return `items2.indexOf(e) == -1;`

All either give `10, 11, or 0.`

How do I make it `return 1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `!includes` as per the other answers, but for the sake of completeness this is how you would keep your approach if you want to:

```
var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(items2, function (e) {
    return !items1.indexOf(e) === -1;
});
```

`ko.utils.arrayFilter` will return items from the array you pass in as the first argument, and you want items from the longer array, so you should pass in `items2`. You want it to return items which are *not* in `items1`, so `indexOf` will return `-1` for those items.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but in the end I used   _.differenceBy(items2, items1, 'Id');

as my arrays were of objects and Id was needed. This seems to work a treat, but your answer was correct for what I asked

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference by filtering the 2nd array for items that are not included in the first.

`const difference = items2.filter(item => !items1.includes(item));`

Comment: I'm looking for the item that was NOT included in the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to check for the difference for example

```js
ar1=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
ar2=[2,10,9,1,2,3,4,5,7]

dif=ar2.filter(x=>!ar1.some(y=>x==y))
console.log(dif)
// or
dif=ar2.filter(x=>!ar1.includes(x))
console.log(dif)
```